# Ruby on Rails ajax DELETE request is not reaching backend

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, turbolinks

I have an ajax request that isnt reaching my backend function. The request gives a status of 200 and steps into the success but it never hits my backend controller method. In my response I get this:

Turbolinks.clearCache()
Turbolinks.visit("http://localhost:3000/session/new", {"action":"replace"})

I dont get any errors in my Dev console. Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Rails version is 6, Turbolinks version is 5.0.1

This is my route in my **routes.rb** file

```
  resources :analyses_groups, :controller => "analyses/groups" do
    delete "remove_mitigation_mapping", on: :collection;
    post "add_mitigation_mapping", on: :collection;
  end
```

My ajax call is in my **index.html.erb** file

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
      $("button.delete_mapping_item").on('click', removeMapping);

    });
    
    var removeMapping = function (event) {
              event.stopPropagation();
            
              var button        = $(this);
              var mapping_type  = button.data("mapping_type");
              var mapping_index = button.data("mapping_index");
              var mapping_name  = button.parents("span").text();
            
              if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove " + mapping_name + "from " + mapping_type + "?")) {
                $("#shade").show();
            
                // Get mitigation_matrix_id
                var row                  = $(this).parents("tr").parents("tr")[0]
                var mitigation_matrix_id = $(row).find(".mitigation_matrix_id").text()
            
                // Set up params for URL
                var param_hash = {
                  "mitigation_matrix_id": mitigation_matrix_id,
                  "mapping_type": mapping_type,
                  "mapping_index": mapping_index,
                }
            
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/analyses_groups/remove_mitigation_mapping" + '?' + $.param(param_hash),
                    type: "DELETE",
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("success");
                        console.log(data);
                      button.closest("tr").remove();
                      $("#shade").hide();
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                      $("#shade").hide();
                    }
                });
              }
            }
```

Comment: @dbugger I edited my post to show the most relevant code. The ajax call is inside the removeMapping function

Comment: Have you checked the developer tools network tab? Does the request send match your expectations? How do you know that the server back-end is not reached? Have you tried placing a breakpoint within the related controller action?

Comment: @3limin4t0r yes I put a breakpoint on my backend and it doesnt reach the endpoint. I had a similar issue with a post request and was able to get it to reach the endpoint so there is something going on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found this kind of ajax to be a major pain to get right due to Rail's auth token and several other messy to resolve issues that need to be handled just right to make it work.

I usually find it's faster/easier to just add a hidden form with a hidden submit button. Slightly more messy, but far less things that you need to get right to have it work, so I typically use this during prototyping and when I need it to work right the first time.

Basically just add a `display:none` form with hidden fields for mitigation_matrix_id, mapping_type and mapping_index. Set them via JS, then use JS to click the hidden submit button. For the JS response, you can just use setup a `action.js.erb` file to handle it. The form should be an ajax form so use `remote: true, local: false` (this works on a wide variety of rails apps, though strictly speaking you only need one of the two for a given version of rails).

Note: There is also a specialized `Rails.ajax` method that can be used too, but that also has a few things that you need to handle right for it to work right.

Answer (score 0):

> In my response I get this:

> Turbolinks.clearCache() >Turbolinks.visit("http://localhost:3000/session/new", {"action":"replace"})

From the above observation, it seems like TurboLinks is intercepting your request and trying to do its thing in the response,

From the ajax call you posted,

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log("success");
    console.log(data);
    button.closest("tr").remove();
    $("#shade").hide();
 },
```

I can safely guess that you are expecting a json response,

Here is what you can try,

add the `dataType` field in the ajax options as json, as below:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/analyses_groups/remove_mitigation_mapping" + '?' + $.param(param_hash),
  type: "DELETE",
  dataType: 'json',//added the expected response type
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("success");
    console.log(data);
    button.closest("tr").remove();
    $("#shade").hide();
  },
  error: function(data) {
    $("#shade").hide();
  }
});
```

Also, in the controller code, if you havent, please respond with a json response and do not use redirect_to, or do not respond with html or js file.

Comment: Setting the dataType to 'json' gave me the same result. Also Im currently using respond_to in the controller code.